# Firebase Auth via company Employee number or secondary email in addition to primary email

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

it is possible to authenticate/login users on the app using their company employee number or through a secondary email ID.

---

Okay, let me try again,
I have managed to implement login via, email+password and phone number+OTP. The following data gets stored in the firestore database:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Primary Email (this email is the charity domain email)
4. Secondary email (user’s personal email like google/outlook etc)
5. Phone No
6. Employee no (employee number given to each volunteers in our charity, normally a six digit number)
   Now I want to implement options to login via stored secondary email or employee number.
   I have come across linking accounts methods, but they mostly relate to social media/google accounts linking.
   I want user to be able to login with secondary email or employee number + password they chose when registering the original account.
   I hope it clarifies my question, and thanks in advance to anyone who could help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Yep - that's certainly possible. However, it's a pretty vague question as there are many possibilities. It would be a good idea to take a look a these two help guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include some code you're having difficulty with and we'll take a look!

Comment: Thanks Jay, probably with my very limited knowledge and skills I am struggling to put forward the question correctly, let me go back and do some homework and re draft my question to enable the wonderful community here to help me,

Comment: You can only use Firebase Auth providers to sign in (Email + Pass, Google, FB etc). So to log in via employee code and password you'll likely have to use a cloud function to find out which employee has that code and probably compare the user entered password to a password stored in firestore. However, please hash the passwords. Do not store plaintext passwords in your db

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mayken for correcting my mistake of posting as answer and teaching me a correct way instead of 'just lecturing' like others,

Comment: Also thanks @S.Ramjit, I will give your answer a try